# Why does nginx randomly throw "403 - Forbidden" errors?

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi, http-status-code-403

I configured Nginx, uwsgi and Django with help of this tutorial:
https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html. But I'm not using a socket, a wsgi ini file, a system wide installation or the emperor mode.

The problem that occurs is a 403 - Forbidden. But this error seems to occur randomly across machines and browsers. For example I can connect to the website via Edge with no problem, but Firefox on the same machine throws a 403 (I use a win home 64 bit machine). Firefox on my Iphone 5 connects with no problem as well as Safari.

I red that this error may occur with wrong permissions but I set the permissions recursively like this:

```
chown -R kltc:kltc /home (axample)
chmod -R ug+r /home (example)
```

The only change I made to Nginx (/etc/nginx/nginx.conf) was uncommenting the 'server_names_hash_bucket_size 64'.

How is this possible ?

Comment: If the permissions were incorrect, the error would occur for all browsers. Use the access log and error log to identify which URIs are causing the 403 response. Also, ensure that you clear the browser cache between tests, otherwise you get confusing results.

Comment: Okay I looked into the error.log and noticed that firefox somehow tries to acces /var/www/html, but why is that so ?